# node express res.redirect from post has post path in URL

Tags: node.js, redirect, post, express

I have a page with several forms that can be submitted, each to a different url. I need post some values then come back to the same page with the result, the problem is that when the post is done and the getOrderById renders, it has the post URL (www../products/new) in the address bar instead of the previous page's addess (www..../orders/:id).

```
function addCoveredProduct(req, res, next){
    registration.addCoveredProduct(req.body, function(result) {
        req.body.notice = result;
        req.params.id = req.body.order_id;
        return next();
    });
}

function handleRedirect(req, res){
  return getOrderById(req, res);
}

function getOrderById(req,res){
    registration.getOrderById(req.params.id, function(result) {
        result.layout = layout;
        if(req.body.notice){
            result.notice = req.body.notice;
        }
        res.render('registration/orders', result);
    });
}

router.post('/products/new', addCoveredProduct, handleRedirect);
```

I can do:

```
return res.redirect('/registration/orders/' + req.body.order_id);
```

in handleRedirect and it would send it to the right page with the right URL, but I don't know how to pass the result data along.

Comment: As the page has many form, did you thought to do post though ajax? Could be more clean..

Comment: I still have to deal with getting the data back and updating the DOM and  several other things, in this case it would get very messy. Regardless, I'd still like to figure out how to solve the above issue as I keep running into it in different situations, if anyone knows please advise.

Comment: No one has an answer to this?